# I want to find if there is a certain name in the students array and if there is to print out true, and false if there isn't

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

```
function createStudent(fn, ln) {  //function
  var person = {       
    firstName: fn,
    lastName: ln
  };
  return person;
}

    var tim = createStudent("Tim", "Plano");
    var matt = createStudent("Matt", "Asant");
    var elie = createStudent("Elie", "Garcia");

    var students = [tim, matt, elie];
//Function      
    findStudentByFirstName(name); {
      for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        if (name[i]=== students.firstName) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }


      }
    }



I do not know what I'm doing wrong, can anyone please help me. Thank you in Advance.
```

Comment: `students` is an array, so `students.firstName` doesn't really make sense. It should be `students[i].firstName`.

Comment: please fix the format. it also looks like you immediately returning on the first check, which is most likely not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a few problems. Declaring your `findStudentByFirstName` function should be using the same `function` keyword that you used when writing `createStudent`. Secondly, you want to move your `return false` outside of the for-loop so that you end up testing *every* student's name before claiming that you couldn't find him/her. Lastly, with your loop, you were probably meaning to access `students[i]` (an array element) rather than `name[i]` (which would be the `(i+1)`th character of your target name string).

```js
function findStudentByFirstName(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        if (name === students[i].firstName) {
          return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

function createStudent(fn, ln) {
    var person = {       
        firstName: fn,
        lastName: ln
    };
    return person;
}

var tim = createStudent("Tim", "Plano");
var matt = createStudent("Matt", "Asant");
var elie = createStudent("Elie", "Garcia");

var students = [tim, matt, elie];

console.log(findStudentByFirstName('Tim')) //=> true
console.log(findStudentByFirstName('Joe')) //=> false
```